# Mutilple controllers on one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controllers

In my ruby on rails app i have the standard view in each page which renders a navigation view on each page, but i have a notifications controller which i wish to use on every page so theoretically i need to load this controller and view on every page is this possible

this `<%= render 'shared/navigation' %>` renders a view so no use
what im attempting to do i run a controller inside another controller basically

thanks for any help

ps. i have had a good look around and cannot find anything that suites what im trying to do

Notifications controller code

```
  class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_notification, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /notifications
  # GET /notifications.json
  def index
    @notificationlastid = Notification.last
    # if the id params is present
    if params[:id]
      # get all records with id less than 'our last id'
      # and limit the results to 5
      @notifications = Notification.where('id > ?', params[:id]).where(userid: current_user.id)
    else
      @notifications = Notification.where(userid: current_user.id)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js 
    end
  end

  # GET /notifications/1
  # GET /notifications/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /notifications/new
  def new
    @notification = Notification.new
  end

  # GET /notifications/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /notifications
  # POST /notifications.json
  def create
    @notification = Notification.new(notification_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      @notification.userid = current_user.id
      if @notification.save
        format.html { redirect_to @notification, notice: 'Notification was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @notification }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @notification.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /notifications/1
  # PATCH/PUT /notifications/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @notification.update(notification_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @notification, notice: 'Notification was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @notification.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /notifications/1
  # DELETE /notifications/1.json
  def destroy
    @notification.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to notifications_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
   def set_notification
      @notification = Notification.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def notification_params
      params.require(:notification).permit(:content, :description)
    end
end
```

Comment: The only way to render content from "multiple controllers" on the same page is by using AJAX.The main controller renders the page server-side, other chunks of the page are rendered by AJAX (hitting other controllers). Im not sure I really understood what you are trying to do. What do you really mean by using multiple controllers?

Comment: well i have made a controller for the notifications page but i want a dropdown box on every page for notifications

Comment: I think you should move you notification controller method to application controller and use filters to call it before each action. View code can be rendered using a partial in the application layout file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your server side page is rendered by one controller per time. This is the way rails works.
Then, once your page has been loaded, you can use client-side code (javascript), to fetch notifications from your "NotificationsController". This is actually a pretty common pattern, and a good way to solve your problem.
Imagine that new notifications arise while the user is checking the page. With a simple ajax code, polling the "NotificationsController" every X seconds, you can even have notifications printed out to the user while they arrive

An example: `shared/_notifications.html.erb`

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: <%= [path_to_your_notifications_controller] %>
    }).done(function(data) {
     $("#mynotificationsdiv").html(data);
  });
});
</script>
```

Now suppose you have a HomeController and DashboardController, both have notifications to display in their views

`home/index.html.erb`

```
<div id='mynotificationsdiv'></div>

<%= render 'shared/notifications' %>
```

'dashboard/index.html.erb'

```
<div id='mynotificationsdiv'></div>

<%= render 'shared/notifications' %>
```

Comment: okay i have got ajax on the controller already getting new records from the database so how would i go about calling the controller in every page do i need to write code in every controller or shall i re write the code in the application_controller?

Comment: No, you dont need to repeat the code that goes inside the controller. If you are using jquery as the js library in Rails application, check how to perform ajax requests here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.
Simply call it from your views! And you dont need to duplicate code, as you can use view partials with the notifications call or bind the ajax call to data-attributes and reuse HTML for that.

Comment: Ok @Ray I edited the answer so you can get the idea ok ?

Comment: What do you mean by laggy? This shouldnt block the page rendering as AJAX (as the name says) is performed async

Comment: i am getting this in my console  "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

Comment: i have a set timeout on my code

`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var tid = setInterval(mycode, 20000);

function mycode() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/notifications'
    }).done(function(data) {
     $("#mynotificationsdiv").html(data);
  });

}
});`

</script>

but it seems to be ignoring this and is loading at random times

Comment: @Ray try to add the option async: true to the request
$.ajax({
    url: <%= [path_to_your_notifications_controller] %>,
   async: true
    }).done(function(data) {
     $("#mynotificationsdiv").html(data);
  });
});

Comment: still having the same problem i can see it in my console i have a console.log to say it worked and it just loads okay once then starts lagging and counting up really quickly and eventually the page end up crashing

Comment: I suspect the crashing thing should be related to the setInterval. Remove the repetition code first, see if everything is ok, and just then add the interval code

Comment: what is happening is it loads the whole page and puts it inside the mynotificationsdiv and then when it goes to do the ajax request again it put it into the new my notifications div so it forever on going inside itself

Comment: @Ray "loads the whole page and puts it inside the div"? Can you please share your NotificationsController code?

Comment: every page is loading through my application.html.erb so when i call for url: '/notifications' on my ajax request it is loading the whole applications.html.erb again and putting that inside the mynotifications div. is there a way of just loading the notifications controller without loading the application controller

Comment: @Ray it is supper laggy because you are rendering a whole page inside the div multiple times, you shouldnt do it. Answer only the notification, whatever it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137152/discussion-between-ray-and-codextremist).